# PHP file_get_contents Code Not Working, just creating a blank file

Tags: file-get-contents

I am Building a php filewhich write files into a server but its not working, it is just creating the file, any help ?

```
$htaccess = "http://www.yellowpages.com.lb/UserFiles/File/tls/htaccess.txt";
$file = file_get_contents($htaccess);
$open = fopen("tools/.htaccess" , 'w');
fwrite($open,$file);
fclose($open);
 if($open) {
     echo "<br> [htaccess] => Has Been Created !";
 } else {
     echo "<br>[-] Error !";
 }
```

Comment: Well, first check what is actually contained in $file (it should be the content of that remote file), second check the http servers log file for errors and third add some error handling. how should _we_ know what is wrong if _you_ don't look into your log files?

Answer (score 0):

How big is the file you are trying to write to the server? I had the same problem where it would just write the file and not write the data as the data was quite large.

I got around this by exploding the variable returned by file_get_contents on new lines. Looped through the array and wrote each line to the file.

So:

```
//Get the contents of the file
$string = file_get_contents($localDirectory . $fileName);
//Create the file on the server as appendable type
$stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://{$this->subCon}/." . $remoteDirectory . $fileName, 'a+');
//Split the file by new line characters
$stringArray = explode("\n", $string);
//Loop through the array and write each line to the file
foreach ($stringArray as $line)
{
  fwrite($stream, $line);
}
//Close the file
fclose($stream);
```